# How can I capture multiple images under one second and save them?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I am trying to capture multiple images under one second, even 10 fps should be fine as well. I am using Huawei Mate20Pro. I tried the handler method but with that 1fps is achieved and reducing the delay any further causes the camera to hang. The code is here:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
            prepareUIForCapture()
            if(isRunning){
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
                restartActivity()
            }else{
                button.text = "Stop"
                handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
                    override fun run(){
                        twoLens.reset()
                        twoLens.isTwoLensShot = true
                        MainActivity.cameraParams.get(dualCamLogicalId).let {
                            if (it?.isOpen == true) {
                                Logd("In onClick. Taking Dual Cam Photo on logical camera: " + dualCamLogicalId)
                                takePicture(this@MainActivity, it)
                                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Captured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                        }
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
                    }
                }, 2000)
            }
            isRunning = !isRunning
        }
```

Here the first shot is after 2 seconds and it captures every 1 second. It works fine. I am looking to increase this rate. I am tring burst capture first.
Here is what I did until now.
In the `takePicture()` method:

```
val captureList = ArrayList<CaptureRequest>()
for (i in 0 until 10){
    captureList.add(params.previewBuilder?.build()!!)
}
params.captureSession?.captureBurst(captureList, StillCaptureSessionCallback(activity, params), params.backgroundHandler)
            params.captureBuilder?.removeTarget(normalParams?.imageReader?.surface!!)
          params.captureBuilder?.removeTarget(wideParams?.imageReader?.surface!!)
```

I think this is working since there is no error or exception. However, I cannot see the saved images. Here is how I am saving them.

```
Toast.makeText(activity, "Burst Captured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
var tempBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
//We need both shots to be done and both images in order to proceed
if (!twoLens.normalShotDone || !twoLens.wideShotDone || (null == twoLens.normalImage)
        || (null == twoLens.wideImage))
        return tempBitmap //Return empty bitmap

    Logd("Normal image timestamp: " + twoLens.normalImage?.timestamp)
    Logd("Wide image timestamp: " + twoLens.wideImage?.timestamp)

    val wideBuffer: ByteBuffer? = twoLens.wideImage!!.planes[0].buffer
    val wideBytes = ByteArray(wideBuffer!!.remaining())
    wideBuffer.get(wideBytes)

    val normalBuffer: ByteBuffer? = twoLens.normalImage!!.planes[0].buffer
    val normalBytes = ByteArray(normalBuffer!!.remaining())
    normalBuffer.get(normalBytes)
    val tempWideBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(wideBytes, 0, wideBytes.size, null)
    val tempNormalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(normalBytes, 0, normalBytes.size, null)
    //Utils.bitmapToMat(tempNormalBitmap, normalMat)
    save(tempWideBitmap, "NormalShot")
    save(tempNormalBitmap, "WideShot")
```

The save method is here:

```
fun save(bytes: Bitmap, tempName: String) {
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val dataDir = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "TwoCameraImagesNew")
    if (!dataDir.exists()) {
        dataDir.mkdir()
    }
    val fileName = tempName + "_IMG_$timeStamp.jpg"
    val fileDir = File(dataDir.path + File.separator + fileName)
    try {
        val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(fileDir)
        bytes.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream)
        //fileOutputStream.write(bytes)
        fileOutputStream.close()
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

However, I am unable to see the saved pictures (it worked fine without burst). Is there a separate way to save burst images? 
Here is my onImageAvailableListener:

```
imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(960, 720, ImageFormat.JPEG, 20)
imageReader?.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageAvailableListener, backgroundHandler)
```

The ImageAvailableListener class acquires the next image (is this correct for burst?) and then calls the method to grab the images and save them (shown above). The complete ImageAvailableListener class is given here:

```
class ImageAvailableListener(private val activity: MainActivity, internal var params: CameraParams) : ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
    override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "ImageReader. Image is available, about to post.")
        val image: Image = reader.acquireNextImage()
        if (MainActivity.twoLens.isTwoLensShot) {

            if (MainActivity.wideAngleId == params.id) {
                twoLens.wideImage = image

            } else if (MainActivity.normalLensId == params.id) {
                twoLens.normalImage = image
            }

            if (twoLens.wideShotDone && twoLens.normalShotDone
                && null != twoLens.wideImage
                && null != twoLens.normalImage) {

                val finalBitmap: Bitmap = DoBokeh(activity, twoLens)
                setCapturedPhoto(activity, params.capturedPhoto, finalBitmap)

                twoLens.normalImage?.close()
                twoLens.wideImage?.close()
            }

        }
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "ImageReader. Post has been set.")
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to get at least 10fps while capturing photos? If not, how should one proceed? How can I save the burst captured images?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately taking photos is not the right approach I guess, cause camera has a recycle time that depends on several factors, including the hardware.
I suggest you to take a video and then retrieve frames.
You can use [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) to take and save the video, then you can extract frames using [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever).
Maybe this last class can give you some problems. If it does, you can use [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) that is way better in my opinion.
To take a frame, you can use the method:

```
retriever.getFrameAtTime(time, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

Be careful, time is in microseconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: I am using multicamera API to capture images from dual cameras at the same time (it is working). I tried capturing video, but it did not work. I don't think that is possible at the moment.

Comment: I know about this API but I've never worked with it. I'm sure that with the approach I suggested you can achieve about 20-25 fps, but using one single camera.